# Can iPhone 3GS make video calls?

Tags: iphone, facetime

"The iPhone 4 was also the first iPhone to include a front-facing camera" (wiki)

So  iPhone 3GS & its Predecessors have no front-camera, then how they (iPhone 3GS & its Predecessors) make video calls like a webcam on a Desktop PC?

If they support that, then how does it work?

Do you look at the iPhone 3GS at the back when making video call? if so, suppose your friend also has video calling function then you can't see anything in the front of your iPhone 3GS??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you look at the iPhone 3GS at the back when making video call?

Correct. Since the iPhone 3GS has no camera on the side of display, you have to turn it around and talk to the non-display side to have your face show up in a video chat. Less than idea, for certain.

Comment: that is a very weird way to do, so is "Face TIme" in iPhone4 a way to fix that issue?

Comment: also, does anyone use iPhone 3GS to make Skype video phone? if they do, then only the receiver (the one who receive the call) can see the face of the caller?

Comment: On the iPhone 4 all the video chat apps like FaceTime, Skype and the like, can use either camera. So you can watch your caller and they can see you.

Answer (score 0):

iSeeU had a [clever solution to this problem](http://gigaom.com/2010/10/15/make-video-calls-on-the-iphone-3gs-with-iseeu/), and though the iSeeU home page appears to be quite down, [the product is still available](https://www.google.com/#q=iseeu+mirror).